# DynamoDB and Lambda connection

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

Consider the following code in Lambda:

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB({region: 'us-east-2', apiVersion: '2012-08-10'});

exports.fn = (event, context, callback) => {
const params = {
    Item: {
        "UserId": {
            S:"dsafsgdhf"
        },
        "Age": {
            N: "28"
        },
        "Height": {
            N: "72"
        },
        "Income": {
            N: "33"
        }
    },
    TableName: "compare-yourself"
};

dynamodb.putItem(params, function(err, data){
   if(err){
       console.log(err);
       callback(err);
   } else {
       console.log(data);
       callback(null, data);
   }
});
```

When I run it, I get the following error:

Response:
{
  "errorMessage": "Handler 'handler' missing on module 'index'"
}

Kindly let me know where I must have gone wrong.

Answer (score 1):

As error states, you are missing `handler`.

You should change this line of code:

```
exports.fn = (event, context, callback) => {
```

to

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
```

The thing is that Lambda function looks for `handler` as entry point, so you can't just rename that function.

Also, from the code you posted here, you are missing parenthesis at the end ( `}` ) to close the function definition.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `Handler` portion shown in the capture below. You should choose whether to use the **Handler** as `index.fn` or `exports.hander` in your code.

[image]